# Send only the part of form or the nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

Is there any way to send part of the form to the controller, like send only `fields_for` to the controller? I have form with multiple attributes, some of them for the model and will be stored in DB and some for API, user will be fill a few fields and then other fields will be rendered (according to api response). So, I need to send my form twice, but I don't want to send whole model form, and just send attributes for the api from this form and then the full form.

Answer (score 0):

When you submit your form, it will send your form data to your controller action, and I think only this action. Also, form will be submit only once

If you want to submit your form twice, why don't you add a custom action to your submit button click. Here you can have two `ajax` calls to your different actions?
Or, you can use `strong parameters` to restrict what will be receive for your individual controller actions